# bash return string between 2 patterns

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

I have this file: 1.txt

```
===================================================================
File: .cvsignore        Status: Up-to-date

   Working revision:    1.1     Thu Jan 16 11:00:00 2020
   Repository revision: 1.1     /usr/local/rancid/var/CVS/Routers/.cvsignore,v
   Sticky Tag:          (none)
   Sticky Date:         (none)
   Sticky Options:      (none)

===================================================================
File: router.db         Status: Up-to-date

   Working revision:    1.6     Fri Jan 17 11:57:39 2020
   Repository revision: 1.6     /usr/local/rancid/var/CVS/Routers/router.db,v
   Sticky Tag:          (none)
   Sticky Date:         (none)
   Sticky Options:      (none)

===================================================================
File: .cvsignore        Status: Up-to-date

   Working revision:    1.1     Thu Jan 16 11:00:00 2020
   Repository revision: 1.1     /usr/local/rancid/var/CVS/Routers/configs/.cvsignore,v
   Sticky Tag:          (none)
   Sticky Date:         (none)
   Sticky Options:      (none)

===================================================================
===================================================================
File: 1.1.1.1       Status: Up-to-date

   Working revision:    1.2     Fri Jan 17 07:56:21 2020
   Repository revision: 1.2     /usr/local/rancid/var/CVS/Routers/configs/1.1.1.1,v
   Sticky Tag:          (none)
   Sticky Date:         (none)
   Sticky Options:      -ko
```

I want to extract string between `File:` and `Status:` (.cvsignore, router.db, 1.1.1.1)

and between `Repository revision:` and `/usr/local/rancid/` (1.1, 1.6, 1.1 )

so final output should be:

> .cvsignore 1.1
>
> router.db 1.6
>
> .cvsignore 1.1
>
> 1.1.1.1 1.2

for filename i created following filter:

```
sed 's/^.*File: //; s/Status:.*$//' 1.txt
```

Output:

```
===================================================================
.cvsignore       

   Working revision:    1.1     Thu Jan 16 11:00:00 2020
   Repository revision: 1.1     /usr/local/rancid/var/CVS/Routers/.cvsignore,v
   Sticky Tag:          (none)
   Sticky Date:         (none)
   Sticky Options:      (none)

===================================================================
router.db        

   Working revision:    1.6     Fri Jan 17 11:57:39 2020
   Repository revision: 1.6     /usr/local/rancid/var/CVS/Routers/router.db,v
   Sticky Tag:          (none)
   Sticky Date:         (none)
   Sticky Options:      (none)

===================================================================
.cvsignore       

   Working revision:    1.1     Thu Jan 16 11:00:00 2020
   Repository revision: 1.1     /usr/local/rancid/var/CVS/Routers/configs/.cvsignore,v
   Sticky Tag:          (none)
   Sticky Date:         (none)
   Sticky Options:      (none)

===================================================================
1.1.1.1      

   Working revision:    1.2     Fri Jan 17 07:56:21 2020
   Repository revision: 1.2     /usr/local/rancid/var/CVS/Routers/configs/172.18.1.24,v
   Sticky Tag:          (none)
   Sticky Date:         (none)
   Sticky Options:      -ko

===================================================================
```

For Repository revision i'm trying

```
sed 's/^.'*Repository revision:' //; s#usr#local#rancid:.*$//' 1.txt
```

But getting

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 15: unterminated `s' command
```

I need one regex for `filename` and second for `Repository revision`

Comment: Do you **really** want text like `# Repository version` to be output after **some** of the values? If so, how do you decide which ones?

Comment: i want it like this one `file=$(awk for filename)` and `repo=$(awk for Repository version)`

Comment: That would not produce the output you say in your question you want so fix your question or, even better, accept one of the answers you already got to the question you asked and then ask a new question. When doing so be clear - in that model would `file` contain a single file name or a list of all file names? It really seems like you're thinking about this the wrong way and so heading down the wrong path here.

Comment: i need to extract `filename` and corresponding `Repository version` so i can use those variables later on in different command

Comment: That's fine but it's extremely unlikely you should do that using the method you propose where you have separate commands for each and run them independently. Instead you should just use the output you get from one of the answers you got to the question you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '/^File:/ { printf "%s # filename ", $2} 
        /Repository revision:/{printf "%s # Repository version\n", $3}' input
.cvsignore # filename 1.1 # Repository version
router.db # filename 1.6 # Repository version
.cvsignore # filename 1.1 # Repository version
1.1.1.1 # filename 1.2 # Repository version
```

Answer (score 2):

Your example isn't clear but is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ awk 'sub(/^[[:space:]]*(File|Repository revision):[[:space:]]*/,""){print $1}' file
.cvsignore
1.1
router.db
1.6
.cvsignore
1.1
1.1.1.1
1.2
```

or maybe this:

```
$ awk 'sub(/^[[:space:]]*(File|Repository revision):[[:space:]]*/,""){printf "%s%s", $1, ((++c)%2 ? OFS : ORS)}' file
.cvsignore 1.1
router.db 1.6
.cvsignore 1.1
1.1.1.1 1.2
```

Comment: yes, that's it !, but i need it in sepate variables, one variable for `filename` and second for `Repository version`

Comment: awk variables or shell variables or something else?

Comment: shell variable, i'll use these expressions in BASH script

Comment: OK and what do you mean by "it" in the sentence "i need **it** in sepate variables"?

Comment: i need awk expression for  `filename ` in one bash variable and awk expression for  `Repository version ` in second variable

Comment: No. Whatever it is you're trying to do, you do not need/want that. That would be an anti-pattern. You asked how to get awk to produce a given output from a given input and you got answers for how to do that. Accept one and if you have a followup question about how to do something with that output in a bash script then ask that as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En '/^File:\s*(\S+).*/{s//\1/;h};/^\s*Repository revision:\s*(\S+).*/{s//\1/;H;g;s/\n/ /p}' file
```

Store the file name in the hold space and append the revision, then replace the introduced newline by a space and print the result.